# Python correlation matrix for categorical data

Tags: python, correlation, categorical-data

I have some data for a charity which contains the amount someone donated and some information about the person who donated like below.

gender  age country  donation_amount

F       25  UK       15

F       65  France   80

M       55  Germany  54

F       41  UK       3

M       74  France   99

I would like to find out which columns are most strongly correlated to the donation amount so I can investigate them further e.g. certain countries donate a lot compared to others so it would be good to target them. This is easy to do with the pandas.corr() function, however this doesn't work with categorical data such as gender, only numerical data such as age.

Does anyone know a way I can do this?

I have read about using pandas.get_dummies() to convert categorical variable into dummy/indicator variables. The problem is I have quite a lot of columns and a couple of them have over 40 different categories for demographics so this get's very big incredibly quickly and hard to interpret (the way I have been doing it at least!).

I also found this article to say you can use spearmanr but also read elsewhere that you shouldn't use spearmanr for categorical data. The pandas.corr(method=spearman) method still doesn't work on categorical data either.
 ([Python: Rank order correlation for categorical data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26489961/python-rank-order-correlation-for-categorical-data))

This is my first post so apologies if I haven't explained myself very well! Please let me know and I will correct anything if needed.